# Property of a semisimple Lie algebra over complex number field

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, lie-algebras

Is the following property true？
  Let $L$ be a finite-dimensional Lie algebra over $\mathbb{C}$. Then $L$ is semisimple if and only if for every $x \in L$, there exists $y, z\in L$, such that $x=[y, z]$.
Remark. For Lie algebra of type $A$, I know that this result is true. However, I do not know other cases.

Comment: The Lie algebra $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbf{C})\ltimes\mathbf{C}^2$ is not semisimple but every element is a commutator (it has only 5 orbits under the action by automorphisms of $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbf{C})\ltimes\mathbf{C}^2$, so this is quite easy).

Comment: It seems anyway that you're primarily interested in the direct implication. Yes, every element is a Lie commutator in a semisimple Lie algebra. This is already asked and answered on MathSE: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/769881/.

Comment: @YCor Thank you.

Comment: PS in my first comment I should have said "only 5 orbits modulo nonzero scalar multiplication"